# Limit movieclip movement on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a movieclip that can be controlled with the arrow keys on the keyboard but I only want the user to only be able to control up to the middle of the stage (it is a submarine and half of my stage is in water), how do I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with a conditional statement to check it's x/y value in relation to the stage's middle. Using the if statement, you can check if submarine.x (your movieclip) is equal to stage.stageWidth/2 (the dynamic width of the stage, halved). In order to stop it, subtract whatever the submarine's speed is.

The code would be:

```
if(submarine.x == stage.stageWidth/2){
submarine.x -= submarineSpeed;
}
```

submarineSpeed is the speed your submarine is moving by the way.

If you hold down the right key (for example) and your submarine is moving 5 pixels to the right per frame, but the condition will subtract 5 pixel per frame if it hits the middle of the stage. Since it is moving 5 frames to both the right and left, it is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by establishing upper and lower limit variables (`minY` and `maxY`), then when you come to move the MovieClip inside the keypress event listener, check whether the current `y` exceeds either limit. If it has gone beyond the limit, set `y` back to the nearest one.

You might need to use slightly different limits depending on the registration point of your submarine MC - for example, if the registration point is at the top of the image, `maxY` would be your stage height minus the height of the MovieClip. You'll also need to change `submarineMC` to your own variable name.

```
var minY:Number = 300; //Set to half the height of your stage
var maxY:Number = 600; //Set to your full stage height

//Inside your keypress event listener, after setting the new y...
if (submarineMC.y > maxY) submarineMC.y = maxY;
else if (submarineMC.y < minY) submarineMC.y = minY;
```